# On table row click focus on that column clicked text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a array of textbox and labels which are toggled in a html table, say the label vl be visible on first and then on the row click the text box are visible , but the problem is on that row click the focus should be on that column textbox clicked in my case am not able to do it.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmj5h2a8/10/)

```js
$('#table1 input').hide();
$('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);

// This shows or hides the button deppending on the inputs
$('#table1 tr').on('change keyup click', function() {
  var text = '';
  $('input', this).each(function() {
    text += $(this).val();
  });

  if (text != '') {
    $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 100);
  } else {
    $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);
  }
});

$('#table1 tr').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("input") || $(e.target).is("th")) {
    return;
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('input', this).toggle();
    $('label', this).toggle();
  } else {
    $('tr.selected input').hide();
    $('tr.selected label').toggle();
    $('tr.selected').toggleClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('label', this).toggle();
    $('input', this).toggle();
  }
});



$('#printdata').click(function() {
  $('.showresult').each(function(index) {
    $('span', this).html('');
    $('span', this).html($('#table1 .selected input').eq(index).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    <th>Column4</th>
    <th>Column5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>data1</label>
      <input type="text" value="data1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data2</label>
      <input type="text" value="data2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data3</label>
      <input type="text" value="data3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data4</label>
      <input type="text" value="data4" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data5</label>
      <select class="dropdown" id="VAt" name="VAt">
        <option value="VAT">VAT</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>data6</label>
      <input type="text" value="data6" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data7</label>
      <input type="text" value="data7" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data8</label>
      <input type="text" value="data8" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data9</label>
      <input type="text" value="data9" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>data10</label>
      <select class="dropdown" id="VAt" name="VAt">
        <option value="VAT">VAT</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>

      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="printdata" type="button" value="printdata" />
<div class="showresult">1: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">2: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">3: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">4: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">5: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vmj5h2a8/12/). binded event on `td` instead of `tr`

Comment: follow @Tushar. also attach event to input focus out

Comment: @Tushar am not sure maybe the demo is not updated or am not getting you the demo don't work

Comment: @Tushar the problem was not with the print button say if the label are visible then to print  or edit the data the user should click on the row at that time on that particular cell clicked the focus should be on text box at one click not again by clicking on text box again

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/vmj5h2a8/13/

Comment: @Raghavendra the toggle is gone in your case but the functionality was the same i was expecting

Comment: yes on focusout you have to implement it like this input.focusout(function() {  $( e.target ).toggleClass('selected');

Comment: @Raghavendra i dint get u :(

Comment: the entire row should be toggled and the clicked cell only should be focused nothing much is required @Raghavendra, your code works perfect to focus but the complete row is not toggeled

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/vmj5h2a8/14/

Comment: include `$( e.target ).next('input').focus();` at the end but inside the else block

Comment: @Pauli try the above suggestion also bye

Comment: @Raghavendra thank you